# How to use multiple exec command in a upstart script?

Tags: linux, upstart

Here is what I tried to run multiple exec command , but I am getting output of email but not for the sms . Is there a way to run the both exec command ?

```
description "starts a kafka consumer for email and sms "
respawn

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

env FOUNDATION_HOME=/opt/home/configs
env VIRTUAL_ENV=/opt/home/virtualenvs/analytics


# run as non privileged user
setuid xxx
setgid xxx

console log

chdir /opt/xxx


exec  stdbuf -oL /opt/xxx/virtualenvs/analytics/bin/python -m yukon.pipelinerunnerexternal /opt/xxx/configs/datastream.pheme_sms  > /tmp/sms.out 2>&1

exec  stdbuf -oL /opt/xxx/virtualenvs/analytics/bin/python -m yukon.pipelinerunnerexternal /opt/xxx/configs/datastream.pheme_email > /tmp/email.out  2>&1

post-start script
    PID=`status kafka_upstart | egrep -oi '([0-9]+)$' | head -n1`
    echo $PID > /var/tmp/kafka_upstart.pid
end script

post-stop script
    rm -f /var/tmp/kafka_upstart.pid
end script
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try concatenating them with `&&` (assuming they're not blocking indefinitely):

```
exec  stdbuf -oL /opt/xxx/virtualenvs/analytics/bin/python -m yukon.pipelinerunnerexternal /opt/xxx/configs/datastream.pheme_sms  > /tmp/sms.out 2>&1 && stdbuf -oL /opt/xxx/virtualenvs/analytics/bin/python -m yukon.pipelinerunnerexternal /opt/xxx/configs/datastream.pheme_email > /tmp/email.out  2>&1
```

Or put the commands in a separate script, `kafkalaunch.sh`, then run the script:

```
exec kafkalaunch.sh
```

Which is more elegant in my opinion.

Comment: thanks , but this ddint work ,I tried this ,script
   exec bash -c   /root/test/script.sh
end script ......>>>where I put the two commands in script.sh

Comment: What's the error you're getting? Looks like the file name has spaces, did you quote it?

Comment: There is no error in the log file , even /var/log/upstart/kafka file has no data. I tried to get the log file in /tmp/sms.out and /tmp/email.out  . Here only email.out is populated not the other one.

Comment: Are you sure the command succeeds if you run it manually outside of upstart, with the same userid you're switching to?

Comment: Hi Yigal, yes the command succeeds if I run manually. If I put them in a shell script , then also it succeeds.

Comment: If I put these two commands in two different conf file e.g sms.conf and email.Conf, they are also running fine. But don't know what is happening when running both.

Comment: Have you tried forking them in the joint `script.sh`? Put an `&` at the end of each line.

Comment: Hi Yigal,#!/bin/sh

/opt/autogrid/virtualenvs/analytics/bin/python -m yukon.pipelinerunnerexternal /opt/xxxx/configs/datastream.pheme_sms > /tmp/sms.out 2>&1 &
/opt/autogrid/virtualenvs/analytics/bin/python -m yukon.pipelinerunnerexternal /opt/xxxx/configs/datastream.pheme_email > /tmp/email.out 2>&1 &  .........now the shell script looks like this . But it is also not running.

Comment: sorry to revive this but I am having a similar issue did you ever figure out the solution besides putting them in two separate files?